# OS showing only one processor

Tags: multi-core

I have 4 core processor but the system is only showing one core.

Note: I am using `acpi=off` in grub entry. If I don't use it, my system crashes.

What to do now?

```
$ inxi -C
CPU:   Single core Intel Core i7-7700HQ (-UP-) cache: 6144 KB
       speed/max: 900/3800 MHz
```

The output of `lscpu` is:

[image: image of output]

Comment: I really doubt this has anything to do with grub or acpi. What is the output of `lscpu`?

Comment: I think it is ,because when i boot without acpi=off it's showing all cores ,but it crashes the system. Output is added in the main thread

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).